# How can I make zip file in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a problem making a zip file in Gradle.
I want to make the zip file like following this.
ProjectName.zip

```
--vertx-socket-server.jar<br/>
--libs
   |
   |--logback-core-1.0.13.jar
   |--commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar
   |--spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
   |--vertx-core-2.0.2-final.jar
               .
               .
```

The ProjectName.zip will be decompressed,

### I want to get the result like this.

```
--vertx-socket-server.jar<br/>
--libs
   |
   |--logback-core-1.0.13.jar
   |--commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar
   |--spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
   |--vertx-core-2.0.2-final.jar
               .
               .
```

---

I need the ProjectNmae.zip when I release it.
I have no idea how to make the build.gradle.
So far, I made the build.gradle file.

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    from 'src/dist'
    baseName = 'vertxWebSocketServer-archive'
    into('libs') {<br/>
        from configurations.runtime
    }
    include 'build/libs/vertx-socket-server.jar'
}

assemble.dependsOn(zip)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what happens? What's the output you get?

Comment: the vertx-socket-server.jar is not included in the ProjectName.zip.

Comment: You make the assembe task, which probably generates the vertx-socket-server.jar, depend on the zip task. So the zip task is executed before the assemble task, and the jar is not generated yet when the zip task is run. It should be `zip.dependsOn(assemble)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, [zip.dependsOn(assemble)] is correct,

Comment: But [include 'build/libs/vertx-socket-server.jar'] is wrong.
I mistook it, I replaced it for [from jar.outputs.files].
It succeeded. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote a post in my blog.
Please, I hope it will be help you like me.
[http://njoonk.blogspot.jp/search/label/Gradle](http://njoonk.blogspot.jp/search/label/Gradle)